# Ctrl-D does not work for readLines(). How to tell R to stop readLines()?

Tags: r

When using the `readLines()` function in R to read stdin from keyboard, `Ctrl-D` does not work as in the bash. Actually, I have tried every possible combination of `Ctrl` and another letter, but none of them worked. How to tell R to stop `readLines()`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work on my windows.